# When I run flutter pub get not working when download package of flutter I have problem

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have a problem when I run `pub get` to add the package of flutter.
I don't know how to solve it.
please I want to solve this problem show in this code.

```
D:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_app...                     
CreateProcessW failed 1392

CreateProcessW failed 1392

CreateProcessW failed 1392

CreateProcessW failed 1392


CreateProcessW failed 1392
CreateProcessW failed 1392

CreateProcessW failed 1392

CreateProcessW failed 1392

CreateProcessW failed 1392

CreateProcessW failed 1392

CreateProcessW failed 1392

CreateProcessW failed 1392
```

**after run**
*flutter doctor --verbose*
found this:

```
D:\flutter\flutter\bin>flutter doctor
C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad>flutter doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1316], locale ar-YE)
    • Flutter version 1.22.4 at D:\flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision 1aafb3a8b9 (3 months ago), 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
    • Engine revision 2c956a31c0
    • Dart version 2.10.4


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
    • Android SDK at D:\AndroidSDK
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = D:\AndroidSDK\AndroidSDK
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin installed
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.30.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 2.25.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM J337V (mobile) • 5200643e534095bf • android-arm • Android 8.0.0 (API 26) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

I install 7-zip to open the archive tar file of the Flutter package.
but the problem still not solved it

Comment: Hi @Hamzah, can you show me the flutter SDK path, I mean copy the flutter SDK path and paste it here, OK?

Comment: And also please run `flutter doctor --verbose` and show me the outputs, thanks

Comment: Hey why answer your question, please delete your answer and instead of that update your question, thanks.

Comment: This path C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad> is your flutter SDK path or not?

Comment: @abbasjafary C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad> is not flutter SDK

Comment: Please show me Flutter path SDK

Comment: @abbasjafary the flutter SDK in D:\flutter\flutter

Comment: And did you use this D:\flutter\flutter\bin> path inside User variables?

Comment: yes ,it's found.

Comment: What is your flutter channel?

Comment: @abbasjafary stable